# Jquery toggle (Show 1 div hide the rest when toggle is activated)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, toggle

The basic idea is that I have a bunch of div's in which each can be toggled (show/hide). When one div is toggled, I'd like for other div's that are currently being shown to hide, thus only allowing one single div to be shown at a time.

It shows user bio's in Wordpress, when opened only 1 bio should be expanded not all bio's. My current code expands all bio's when using the toggle function:

```
<?php
$category_text = get_the_hrb_user_bio($user);

if (strlen($category_text) > $max_lenght) { ?>
    <div class="info short">
        <?php echo substr($category_text, 0, 350) . "..."; ?>
        <br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="r_more">Read More..</a>
    </div>

    <div class="info long" style="display:none;">
        <?php echo $category_text; ?>
        <br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="r_less">Read less..</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.r_more').click(function () {
                $('.short').hide();
                $('.long').show();
            });
            $('.r_less').click(function () {
                $('.long').hide();
                $('.short').show();
            })
        });
    </script>

<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="info short">
        <?php echo the_hrb_user_bio($user); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: please use `http://jqueryui.com/` for this type of question

Comment: I'm guessing you're not in a really good mood today.

Comment: No @lloyd not at all becuase it's wordpress question bank so , i don't think so it's jquery question bank.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `$('.short').hide();` or `$('.long').show();` is hiding or showing **all** divs that have attribute `class="short"` or `class="long"` respectively.
Here is the solition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.r_more').click(function() {
            $('.short').show(); //shows all short infos
            $('.long').hide(); //hide all full infos
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.hide(); //shows only one block
            parent.next().show(); //shows only one block
        });
        $('.r_less').click(function() {
            $('.short').show(); //shows all short infos
            $('.long').hide(); //hide all full infos
        });
    });
</script>
```

or, a little bit optimized

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var allShorts = $('.short');
        var allLongs = $('.long');
        $('.r_more').click(function() {
            allShorts.show(); //shows all short infos
            allLongs.hide(); //hide all full infos
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.hide(); //hides only one block
            parent.next().show(); //shows only one block
        });
        $('.r_less').click(function() {
            // we don't need this, as at this moment all long infos
            // should be hided, except one block
            // allLongs.hide(); //hide all full infos
            // allShorts.show(); //shows all short infos
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.hide(); //hides only one block
            parent.prev().show(); //shows only one block
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Managed to fix the code like this. See next post

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```js
<div class="freelancer-description">
 <?php 
 $category_text = get_the_hrb_user_bio( $user );
 if (strlen($category_text) > $max_lenght)  { ?>
  <div class="info short">
  <?php echo substr( $category_text,0,350 ) . "..."; ?>
  <br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="r_more">Read More..</a>
  </div>

  <div class="info long" style="display:none;">
   <?php echo $category_text; ?>
  <br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="r_less">Read less..</a>
  </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.r_more').click(function() {
 $(this).parents('.freelancer-description').find('.short').hide();
 $(this).parents('.freelancer-description').find('.long').show();
 });
    $('.r_less').click(function() {
 $(this).parents('.freelancer-description').find('.long').hide();
 $(this).parents('.freelancer-description').find('.short').show();
 })
 });
 </script>
  <?php } else { ?> 
  <div class="info short">
  <?php echo the_hrb_user_bio( $user ); ?>
  </div>
 <?php } ?> 
   </div>
```